# Make a button display an text input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uitableview

So I am new on app development. I am currently using swift on Xcode 6.1 and I want to make a button to create a Table View Cell. So I need to do when the button is clicked prompt a text input with a name for you Cell, and after this name is typed create the cell.

My button and table view are:

- @IBOutlet weak var charListIPhone: UITableView!
- @IBOutlet weak var addCharIPhone: UIButton!

Comment: Please show the code from your attempt at this and explain which part you don't understand.

Comment: What? I don't get what you want.

Comment: @Skal, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Is not that is giving me any error, I just don't know how to proceed. How can I take text input from the user and make it as a cell?

Comment: Imagine a Table View, and the user can create table view cells with the name that he wants, this is basically what I am trying to do